# css border-color does not work in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser

The code is looking like this:

```
<img style='border-color:green;border-radius:1px;' src='/Pic.jpg' width='25px' height='25px'/>
```

This is working in IE 9, but not in Chrome Version 28.0.1500.72. I don't get the green border color.

What is wrong here? Is there any workaround to solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chrome isn't setting default border styles. Try `border:1px solid green;`.

Alternatively, split it into invididual properties (functionally identical as above):

```
border-width:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:green;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have set the color of the border but you haven't defined a size (or type) so you don't have a border to become green.

Try:

```
border: 1px solid green;
```